# Setting image view in linear layout programmatically in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

I am trying to set image in image view and then append it to Linear layout when I click button it doesnt show anything this what i have done yet

```
fun click(view: View) {
        val dimensionInDp = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 60f,
            DisplayMetrics()
        )
        val params = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(dimensionInDp.toInt(),
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        )
        val imageView = ImageView(this)
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ac)
        imageView.id= ViewCompat.generateViewId()
        imageView.layoutParams=params
        imageView.visibility= View.VISIBLE
        card_layout.addView(imageView)
    }
```

It isnt showing image and I dont know why

**Log Cat**

```
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:63)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0!(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:430)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:656)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:798)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:738)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:869)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:832)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:518)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:426)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:377)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.view.ViewGroup androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:896)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:693)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:170)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void com.example.cardgame.MainActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (MainActivity.kt:19)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6964)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1123)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2752)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2870)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1573)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:105)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:156)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6605)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:999)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.434 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:889)
2020-08-16 21:12:12.500 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
2020-08-16 21:12:12.568 7805-7830/com.example.cardgame I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-08-16 21:12:12.579 7805-7830/com.example.cardgame W/linker: /vendor/lib64/libhwuibp.so: unused DT entry: type 0xf arg 0xe3a
2020-08-16 21:12:13.489 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/hwaps: JNI_OnLoad
2020-08-16 21:12:13.629 7805-7805/com.example.cardgame I/BitmapFactory: set decoder allocator to gralloc
```

This is the log when I click button

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the error message (probably above the logs you pasted here).

Regardless, I can't directly tell what's wrong but I assume there are 2 alternative (better) ways to do what you are doing

If there is only 1 ImageView that you want to add (meaning either 0 or 1) you should just set the View visibility to VISIBLE in your code in the click method and have it set to GONE (or invisible) in xml

If there are multiple, you probably want a recyclerview and also you would need scrolling at some point anyways if you can add multiple images.

If it's a mixture of these 2, meaning you have more than 1 but don't require scrolling (like with a maximum of 3 items for example) you should also just use View visibility instead of a Recyclerview

Adding views programatically should be the last resort if nothing else works, in this case it would though